# What aviation-related TV shows are there?

Tags: airport, accidents, general-aviation

This question aims to serve as a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) resource.

Feel free to edit the list of aviation-related TV shows below!

**Related:** [What aviation-related movies are there?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1375/what-aviation-related-movies-are-there/1376)

Comment: Meta discussion simultaneously started: [Are these questions on-topic? TV shows/movies](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/234)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Disasters

- [Air Crash Investigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayday_%28TV_series%29) (a.k.a. Mayday): **2002 - now** -
- [Aircrash Confidential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircrash_Confidential): **2011 - now** -
- [Seconds From Disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconds_from_disaster): **2004 - now** - not all aircraft related
- [Terror In The Skies](http://www.channel4.com/programmes/terror-in-the-skies): **2013 - now** -

### Documentaries

- [Airplane Repo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airplane_Repo): **2010 - now** -
- [American Fighter Pilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AFP%3a_American_Fighter_Pilot): **2002** -
- [Dangerous Flights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangerous_Flights): **2012 - now** - follows a team of ferry pilots
- [Flying Wild Alaska](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Wild_Alaska): **2011 - now** -
- [Jet Stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetstream_%28TV_series%29): **2008** -  follows 8 pilots training with the Royal Canadian Air Force to fly one of the most advanced supersonic tactical fighter jets in the world — the CF-18 Hornet
- [Ice Pilots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice_Pilots_NWT):  **2009 - now** -
- [Mighty Planes](http://www.discovery.ca/showpage.aspx?sid=38987): **2012 - now** - series about unique large aircraft
- [The Aviators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Aviators_%28TV_series%29): **2010 - now** -

### Airports

- [Airport 24/7: Miami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airport_24/7%3a_Miami): **2012 - now** - follows the daily life at Miami International Airport
- [Animal Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal_Airport): **2000 - now** -
- [Ultimate Airport: Dubai](http://natgeotv.com/uk/ultimate-airport-dubai): **2013 - now** - follows the daily life and construction at the world's 2nd busiest airport<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World%27s_busiest_airports_by_international_passenger_traffic)</sup>

### Sitcoms

- [Air America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_America_%28TV_series%29)
- [Come Fly With Me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Come_Fly_with_Me_%282010_TV_series%29)
- [Wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wings_%28NBC_TV_series%29): **1990 - 1997** - drama/comedy

### Dramas

- [AirWolf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airwolf)
- [Black Sheep Squadron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baa_Baa_Black_Sheep_%28TV_series%29)
- [Blue Thunder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Thunder_%28TV_series%29)
- [El Señor de los Cielos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Se%C3%B1or_de_los_Cielos): **2013 - now** - Spanish language, English subtitles
- [LAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAX_%28TV_series%29)
- [Pan Am](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pan_Am_%28TV_series%29)
- [Pensacola: Wings of Gold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pensacola%3a_Wings_of_Gold)
- [SuperCarrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercarrier_%28TV_series%29)