# What aviation-related movies are there?

Tags: general-aviation

This question aims to serve as a [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) resource.

Feel free to edit the list of aviation-related movies below!

**Related:** [What aviation-related TV shows are there?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/what-aviation-related-tv-shows-are-there/1373)

Comment: Meta discussion simultaneously started: [Are these questions on-topic? TV shows/movies](http://meta.aviation.stackexchange.com/q/234)

Comment: I love these I hope they stay :)

Comment: It is not about aviation, it is about tv shows.

Comment: Isn't this a list question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Action

- [Top Gun](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092099/)

### Comedy

- [Airplane!](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080339/)
- [Pushing Tin](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120797/)

### Drama

- [Airport](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065377/)
- [Cloud Dancer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080545/)
- [Flight](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1907668/)
- [Ground Control](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137799/)
- [The Aviator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338751/)
- [The Right Stuff](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086197/)

### Factual

- [One Six Right](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475994/)
- [Speed and Angels](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1112756/)
- [United 93](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0475276/)

### [Turner Classic Movies](http://www.tcm.com/this-month/article/160793|0/Aviation-In-Film-Tuesdays-in-July.html)

- TCM lists 43 aviation movies in it's catalogue

### Miscellaneous

- [Sky Captain and the World of Tomorrow](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0346156/?ref_=nv_sr_1)
- [Airport](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0065377/?ref_=nv_sr_1)
- [Airport 1975](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071110/?ref_=nv_sr_2)
- [Airport '77](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075648/?ref_=nv_sr_3)
- [Concorde... Airport '79](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078740/?ref_=nv_sr_4)
- [Wings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wings_(1927_film))

  - Best picture, 1st Academy Awards (1927)
- [Fire Birds](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099575/?ref_=nv_sr_3)
- [Air Force One](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118571/?ref_=nv_sr_1)
- [633 Squadron](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057811/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)
- [Independence Day](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116629/?ref_=nv_sr_2)
- [Independence Day: Resurgence](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1628841/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

  - Coming soon to a theatre near you!
- [Bombers B-52](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050204/?ref_=fn_al_tt_5)
- [The Bridges at Toko-Ri](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046806/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)
- [A Gathering of Eagles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0057090/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_29)
- [Air Cadet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043270/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_66)
- [Those Magnificent Men in Their Flying Machines or How I Flew from London to Paris in 25 hours 11 minutes](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059797/?ref_=nv_sr_1)
- [Bat*21](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094712/?ref_=fn_tt_tt_11)
- [The Flight of the Phoenix](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0059183/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_20)

  - The good one with Jimmy Stewart. Not the remake.
- [No Highway in the Sky](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043859/?ref_=nm_flmg_act_54)
- [Flight of the Navigator](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091059/?ref_=nv_sr_5)
- [Flightplan](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0408790)